# How to add dropdown list in kendo grid

Tags: angular, angular6, kendo-grid

Hi I am trying to add drop-down list in the kendo-grid column but the data is not getting loaded in drop-down list.

I am trying to load the data from array.

html file code

```
<kendo-grid-column  title="Status Comments" width="200">
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let- 
rowIndex="rowIndex">
    <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="listItems"
  [textField]="'ProductName'"
  [valueField]="'ProductID'"
  [defaultItem]="placeHolder"
  [valuePrimitive]="true"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
     >

</kendo-dropdownlist>
<div class="example-config">
    Selected Item: {{selectedValue}}
</div>
```

ts file code

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
public listItems: Array<Product> = [];
public placeHolder: Product = { ProductName: 'Select product...', ProductId: null };
 public selectedValue: Product = this.listItems[1]
constructor (@Inject(DataService) private dataService: DataService) { }
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe(
    (data) => this.listItems = data
  );
}
```

}
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f4If.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please check here..
[image]
html file

```
 <kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [height]="410">
 <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="40">
 </kendo-grid-column>
 <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="50">
 </kendo-grid-column>
 <kendo-grid-column title="In stock" width="80">
 <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
 <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="listItems">
 </kendo-dropdownlist>
 </ng-template>
 </kendo-grid-column>
 </kendo-grid>
```

ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { products } from './product';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
public gridData: any[] = products;
public listItems: Array<string> = ["X-Small", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "X-Large", 
"2X-Large"];
}
```

product.ts

```
 export const products = [{
    "ProductID": 1,
    "ProductName": "Chai",
    "SupplierID": 1,
    "CategoryID": 1,
    "QuantityPerUnit": "10 boxes x 20 bags",
    "UnitPrice": 18.0000,
    "UnitsInStock": 39,
    "UnitsOnOrder": 0,
    "ReorderLevel": 10,
    "Discontinued": false,
    "Category": {
        "CategoryID": 1,
        "CategoryName": "Beverages",
        "Description": "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
    }
}, {
    "ProductID": 2,
    "ProductName": "Chang",
    "SupplierID": 1,
    "CategoryID": 1,
    "QuantityPerUnit": "24 - 12 oz bottles",
    "UnitPrice": 19.0000,
    "UnitsInStock": 17,
    "UnitsOnOrder": 40,
    "ReorderLevel": 25,
        "Discontinued": false,
        "Category": {
            "CategoryID": 1,
            "CategoryName": "Beverages",
            "Description": "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
        }
    }
    ];
```

Comment: Can you please send me the code How to bind **CategoryName** to dropdownlist ? Which is present in Product.ts file.